# How to use trained artifacts from AzureML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

After creating a model with Azure designer and creating a Real-time inference pipeline I would like to use the trained artifacts in a local script. I'm trying to look for the model.py in the Azure Storage Explorer but cannot find it, or the python where the trained model is called using pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

To use a real-time inference pipeline you must call the REST endpoint with an authentication key.

See: https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-create-training-and-inferencing-pipelines-with-azure-ml-designer/

The end of the post shows how to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

The model artifacts can be downloaded using az ml model download - that will get all of the files.